# How to detect devices (Android, iOS, windows) in AMP website

Tags: amp-html, browser-detection

I have made a website in AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages). I want to show some content in android but not in iOS.
Is there any way to detect android and iOS using AMP?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `amp-access` for this, You have to identify `user-agent` in `authorization` and set a flag. [here](https://glitch.com/~tasteful-swift) is an example which does that. In the example `device-detection` checks if the device is `android` otherwise returns `Iphone`