# How to detect mobile device (android or iOS) with AMP

Tags: amp-html, device-detection

I am trying to display different content based on the users device. One button for android devices another button for iOS devices. I found a bit of an answer using `req.headers["user-agent"]` but I do not know how to implement that solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039020/how-to-detect-devices-android-ios-windows-in-amp-website/56703654#56703654 this might help you